# iDevices as HTTP Live Streaming server

Tags: ios, http-streaming

From what have gathered so far, Apple provided tools to make Mac to act as HTTP Live Streaming server.  But my goal is different.  I want to make iDevices to be the HTTP Live Streaming server.  (for local network only)

Can it be done at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes and no. Apple does not provide a way to stream encoded media data, so that part is 100% up to you. Also, Apple does not provide a way to access encoded frames directly (i.e. you can easily get an encoded file or the raw frames, but not easily get "encoded frames'). So you need to develop a way to get these encoded frames from the files for streaming, or encode the raw frames on the fly.

It may or may not fit your use case, but if you first right the streamer portion, you should be able to say small/short clips to disk, and stream them out as they are created with minimal overall latency.

Comment: I actually was looking for the second half of your answer.  Do you know any resources on implement/format the HLS?